# I Wanted to access my admin panel page through the menu item of my android app

Tags: java, android, url, menu

In my android app I am having a menu item logout.I wanted to add another menu item My Panel which redirects into admin panel page gmumbai.co.in/admin.How to accomplish this.Please help me with a sample code.Thanks in advance.

```
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_overview, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        Intent intent;

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_logout:
                app = ((MyApplication) getApplicationContext());
                app.logOut();
                intent = new Intent(overview.this, LoginActivity.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                overview.this.startActivity(intent);
                overview.this.finish();
                return true;
            case R.id.action_MyPanel:
                Uri uri=Uri.parse("http://gmumbai.co.in/admin");
                overview.this.startActivity(new Intent (Intent.ACTION_VIEW,uri));
                overview.this.finish();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}

    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context="com.gmumbai.gvendor.overview">
    <item android:id="@+id/action_logout" android:title="@string/action_logout"
        android:orderInCategory="100" app:showAsAction="never" />
    <item android:id="@+id/action_MyPanel" android:title="@string/action_MyPanel"
        android:orderInCategory="100" app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

Comment: do you want to open web browser by clicking on menu item?

Comment: What did you do to achieve this? Show your code/efforts here.StackOverflow is not a code writing service. If you have a problem with your code, please provide Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: please review my code.I have added two menu items.but Iam not able to see the second menu item my panel where i wanted to access my admin panel page.so only i asked for a sample code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For adding a menu entry, try this:

**res/menu/main_menu.xml**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_logout"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_logout"
        android:title="Logout"
        app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_redirAdmin"
        android:icon="@drawable/admin_console"
        android:title="Admin Console"
        app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView">
    </item>
</menu>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    return true;
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_logout:
            //Logout
            return true;
        case R.id.action_redirAdmin:
            //Goto AdminConsole
            //startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, AdminConsole.class));
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

If you are trying to display a webpage in your view, make sure you have a WebView in AdminConsole.java

For adding WebView, try this:

**admin_console_activity.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"  
    android:layout_width="match_parent"  
    android:layout_height="match_parent"  
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >  

    <WebView  
        android:id="@+id/adminConsoleWebView"  
        android:layout_width="match_parent"  
        android:layout_height="match_parent"  
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"  
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"  
        android:layout_marginTop="42dp" />  
  </RelativeLayout>
```

**AdminConsole.java**

```
private WebView mWebView;

    @Override  
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
        setContentView(R.layout.admin_console_activity);  

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.adminConsoleWebView);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("http://gmumbai.co.in/admin");
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much.I will try this.Can you pleae guide me how to add webview in my java class

Comment: See my updated answer.
Please mark it correct/thumbs up if it helped. Thanks